# How to automatically close a DXL scripted Dialog Box (opened from the module) when that Module is closed

Tags: ibm-doors

**PROBLEM:** 
A DXL scripted Dialog box is persistent and does not close even when the module is closed.

**CURRENT ISSUE:** 
Confuses the user while opening another module even when the DXL scripted Dialog Box for the previous module is open, even when that module itself is closed.

**EXPECTED RESULT:** 
When a module is closed, all the DXL Dialog Boxes (opened for that module) should be closed.

Any Suggestions

Comment: There is not enough information in this post to give you an answer. Can you post some of the code that is causing the dialog box to open?

Comment: To be more clear.. I would need to restrict only one DXL scripted dialog box for a module which is open. Even wen the user is trying 2 invoke the same DXL scripted dialog box again for a module, the module should not allow.

Cheers
Haresh

Comment: You can have any script from the dxl reference PDF for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your post in the DOORS LinkedIn forum was answered with the following (I am re-posting here for the sake Stack Overflow completeness):

```
DB TestDialog = create(current Module, "TEST DIALOG", styleSubWindow)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is force the user to complete their interaction with the dialog box before they continue on. The only way to guarantee that the previous dialog box gets closed before the script runs again is to `block` all other windows until the script is complete.

You can do this by using `block(DB modalBox)` instead of `show(DB box)`. `show` allows the user to continue to interact with DOORS while the dialog is open, where `block` prevents all interaction with other windows until the dialog is released using `release(DB modalBox)`. If you need the user to be able to interact with the Module or Database window while the dialog box is open, you will not be able to use this method.

I hope this helps.